# VBA Excel, What method for searching should I put in this loop to save processing time?

Tags: search, find

OK here is a code I created (with help from Stackoverflow users) that compares two worksheets, a bank statement (Deposits and Credits) with an internally created report (June PB INS). The If statement is checking to see if the date and amount transferred match on the two sheets. When this condition is met the Deposits and Credits sheet row is highlighted and the location of the match from wsPB is written in the column next to the Deposits ws amount

Essentially **this code works but is very slow** because wsPB (June PB INS) is 70k rows. Can I use a search function to make it faster?

```
Sub StackCombined()

Dim TransDate As String
Dim TransAmt As Long
Dim PBINSDate As String
Dim PBINSAmt As Long

Dim wsPB As Worksheet
Dim Sht1LastRow As Long, Sht2LastRow As Long
Dim x2 As Long, x2count As Long, x1 As Long, x1count As Long
' Sht1LastRow finds the last row of Deposits and Credits with a value
Sht1LastRow = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(10000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Sht2LastRow finds the last row of June PB INS with a value
Sht2LastRow = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Call worksheet June PB INS just wsPB
Set wsPB = Sheets("June PB INS")
With Sheets("Deposits And Credits")

    For x1 = 2 To Sht1LastRow

        For x2 = 2 To Sht2LastRow
            'TransDate is the transaction date recorded from the bank
            TransDate = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(x1, 1).Value
            'PBINSDate is the transaction date recorded internally through EPIC
            PBINSDate = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(x2, 1).Value
            'TransAmt is the bank statements amount of the transaction
            TransAmt = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(x1, 3).Value

                'The Dates must match
                'The amount must either column 2, single record, OR column 15, daily record
                'if these two conditions are met, highlight the bank statement and record where the match was found
                If TransDate = PBINSDate _
                And (TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(x2, 2) _
                    Or _
                    TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(x2, 15) _
                ) _
                Then
                    .Cells(x1, 12).Value = wsPB.Cells(x2, 1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows(x1 & ":" & x1).Select
                       With Selection.Interior
                          .Pattern = xlSolid
                          .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                          .Color = 5296274
                          .TintAndShade = 0
                          .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                      End With
               End If
        Next x2
    Next x1
End With
End Sub
```